# Как выбрать элемент на js?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код php

```
<?php
$data = parse_ini_file("likes.ini"); // Парсим INI-файл 
for($id=1; $id<4;$id++){
     $likes = $data[$id]; // Получаем количество лайков у статьи
     ?>
     <div id="like" data-id="<?=$id?>">
        <?=$likes?>
     </div>
     <?php
}?>
```

и на js

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#like").bind("click", function (event) {
                /*if (get_cookie("VoiceLook") != "Yes") {*/
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "like.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: ("id=" + $("#like").attr("data-id")),
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result) {
                                $("#like").text(Number($("#like").text()) + 1);
                            } else alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                    /*document.cookie = "VoiceLook=Yes";
                }
                else{
                    alert("Вы уже голосовали!");
                }*/
            });
        });



        function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
            var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            if (results)
                return (unescape(results[2]));
            else
                return null;
        }
    </script>
```

То есть на странице выводится несколько div с одинаковым id при нажатии которого число должно увеличиться на +1. (это система лайков с записью в файл через like.php). Но у меня получается что в файл like.php все время передается только id=1 (первого дива) и получается что увеличить на +1 можно только 1 див. Как можно это исправить?

Как я понимаю проблема в js, он не может правильно понять на который id я нажимаю в связи с чем постоянно отправляет id=1.

Comment: id должно быть уникальным.

Comment: Из курсов html я читал это. А как тогда делать? Не писать же 30 функций для 30 id.

Comment: @Максим Вам ответил Вадим Лешкевич. Используйте контекст при отправке данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID должен быть уникальным, только один раз на странице, по этому при клике у вас выбирается первый элемент `с id="like"` на странице, добавьте вашему элементу `class="like"`

```
<?php
$data = parse_ini_file("likes.ini"); // Парсим INI-файл 
for($id=1; $id<4;$id++){
     $likes = $data[$id]; // Получаем количество лайков у статьи
?>
<div class="like" id="like" data-id="<?=$id?>">
    <?=$likes?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

И в js обрабатывайте событие клика по элементу с классом like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".like").bind("click", function (event) {
            /*if (get_cookie("VoiceLook") != "Yes") {*/
                var that = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "like.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ("id=" + that.attr("data-id")),
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result) {
                            that.text(Number(that.text()) + 1);
                        } else alert("Error");
                    }
                });
                /*document.cookie = "VoiceLook=Yes";
            }
            else{
                alert("Вы уже голосовали!");
            }*/
        });
    });



    function get_cookie(cookie_name) {
        var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        if (results)
            return (unescape(results[2]));
        else
            return null;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Все верно. Большое спасибо! var that = $(this) позволяет на работать именно с тем классом на который мы нажали?

Comment: Вообще `$(this)` выбирает именно то элемент, с которым случилось событие, в данной ситуации `click`, а `var that = $(this)`, это мы просто `$(this)` присваиваем переменной, чтоб потом использовать в остальных местах

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете использовать на одной странице несколько элементов с одинаковыми `id` (как вы сделали для `id="like"`). В вашем случае `$("#like")` всегда будет возвращать первый элемент.
Используйте `class='like'` вместо `id`